# How to cast ctypes c_void_p object to actual type?

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a C library wrapped function using ctypes, looking like this

```
rrpLib.getParameterValueAsPointer.restype = c_void_p
def getParameterValueAsPointer(parHandle):  
   return rrpLib.getParameterValueAsPointer(parHandle)
```

where rrpLib is the ctypes CDLL object.
and where for a certain parHandle, the underlying object is a known double*.

How can I cast the c_void_p object in order to get the actual double number on the python side?

Comment: I'm new to ctypes and everything is not crystal clear.
The rrpLib.getParameterValueAsPointer.restype is set to c_void_p
I guess the manual creation is redunant?

I still don't see how to cast from c_void_p to double.

Answer (score 2):

Figured this one out, thanks to eryksun for their suggestion.
The proper way seems to be to do

```
my_void_val = getParameterValueAsPointer(aParaHandle)
my_dbl_ptr = cast(my_void_val , POINTER(c_double))
print(my_dbl_ptr[0])
```

Gives the correct value.

Comment: Problem is return type is not always double*. It can be of any type in fact.

Comment: If it's possible to determine how to cast based on `aParahandle`, you could set [`errcheck`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes#ctypes._FuncPtr.errcheck) to a function that returns the dereferenced pointer value.